# How to increase the column size in django template?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

- Language: Python
- Framework: Django

I can strech(adjust) rows through cursor but problem is i cant do the same for column (as shown in picture)

here is the code i used:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h2>New Blog</h2><br>

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success ml-2" value="save">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog_list' %}" role="button">Cancel</a>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

[image: new blog]

here are my views.py and models.py files

https://github.com/YashMarmat/personal-documnets-.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Forms.py file in your app, then add a custom model in it as shown below:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea

class BlogCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'author')
        widgets = {
            'body': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

Replace the code present in views.py with the below one:

```
class BlogCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = "blog_new.html"
    form_class = BlogCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("blog_list")
    login_url = 'login'
```

Comment: But I didn't use a custom model I used django default model means no forms.py file

Comment: @YashMarmat Show us your view.py, or just that particular view

Comment: i provided a link for my views.py and model.py files above or just visit here https://github.com/YashMarmat/personal-documnets-.git

Comment: @YashMarmat check answer now